# Issues installing Ultima Online

Tags: 18.04, games

I've been trying to install *Ultima Online Classic* for a few days now with no success. I'm new to Linux, so I'm not sure what is wrong. I have *Wine* installed and configured.

Here are the details of the failure:

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x020e3498 in 32-bit code (0xf7c6c993).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:f7c6c993 ESP:09c0fc58 EBP:09c0fce8 EFLAGS:00010287(  R- --  I S - -P-C)
 EAX:020df4a8 EBX:f7d03000 ECX:00004000 EDX:5911f1b2
 ESI:00004000 EDI:020cf408
Stack dump:
0x09c0fc58:  7dd84000 7dd65056 5911f1b2 020df4a8
0x09c0fc68:  00004000 7b476f10 00000440 00000000
0x09c0fc78:  09c0fd58 020cf4a8 5911f1b2 00004000
0x09c0fc88:  7dd84000 00000000 09c0fcb8 7bc3c896
0x09c0fc98:  09c0fcc0 7bc3c9e6 09c0fcc0 7dd84000
0x09c0fca8:  09c0fce8 7dd5f42d 7dd84000 020cf408
Backtrace:
=>0 0xf7c6c993 in libc.so.6 (+0x141993) (0x09c0fce8)
  1 0x7dd65056 in winhttp (+0x15055) (0x09c0fce8)
  2 0x7dd6d77b WinHttpReadData+0x13a() in winhttp (0x09c0fd28)
  3 0x0040c2f2 in uo.bin (+0xc2f1) (0x09c0fd70)
  4 0x0040bb10 in uo.bin (+0xbb0f) (0x07f15d80)
  5 0x07f164f0 (0x004803d4)
  6 0x0040ae40 in uo.bin (+0xae3f) (0x0040acf0)
  7 0x00000018 (0xe8f18b56)
0xf7c6c993: repe movq   0xfffffff0(%eax,%ecx,1),%mm1
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (167 modules)
PE    400000-  48f000   Export          uo.bin
PE   30a0000- 32b6000   Deferred        nss3
PE  10000000-10051000   Deferred        patchui
PE  661c0000-662a4000   Deferred        mozglue
PE  69e40000-6d7d7000   Deferred        xul
PE  70a80000-70b5d000   Deferred        lgpllibs
ELF 7ac00000-7ac84000   Deferred        riched20<elf>
  \-PE  7ac10000-7ac84000   \               riched20
ELF 7b1d7000-7b200000   Deferred        mlang<elf>
  \-PE  7b1e0000-7b200000   \               mlang
ELF 7b400000-7b7ec000   Deferred        kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b420000-7b7ec000   \               kernel32
ELF 7b80f000-7b8c9000   Deferred        jscript<elf>
  \-PE  7b820000-7b8c9000   \               jscript
ELF 7b8c9000-7b900000   Deferred        msctf<elf>
  \-PE  7b8d0000-7b900000   \               msctf
ELF 7ba08000-7ba28000   Deferred        dnsapi<elf>
  \-PE  7ba10000-7ba28000   \               dnsapi
ELF 7ba28000-7ba46000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF 7ba48000-7ba60000   Deferred        shcore<elf>
  \-PE  7ba50000-7ba60000   \               shcore
ELF 7ba60000-7ba77000   Deferred        dwmapi<elf>
  \-PE  7ba70000-7ba77000   \               dwmapi
ELF 7ba77000-7ba8f000   Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
ELF 7ba8f000-7bb70000   Deferred        libgcrypt.so.20
ELF 7bb70000-7bc00000   Deferred        libsystemd.so.0
ELF 7bc00000-7bcfd000   Deferred        ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcfd000   \               ntdll
ELF 7bcfd000-7bd13000   Deferred        liblz4.so.1
ELF 7bd13000-7bd3f000   Deferred        liblzma.so.5
ELF 7bd3f000-7bd9a000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF 7bd9a000-7bda7000   Deferred        libkrb5support.so.0
ELF 7bda7000-7bddc000   Deferred        libk5crypto.so.3
ELF 7bddc000-7beb8000   Deferred        libkrb5.so.3
ELF 7beb8000-7becc000   Deferred        libavahi-client.so.3
ELF 7becc000-7bf20000   Deferred        libgssapi_krb5.so.2
ELF 7bf20000-7bfb2000   Deferred        libcups.so.2
ELF 7bfb2000-7bfcc000   Deferred        kerberos<elf>
  \-PE  7bfc0000-7bfcc000   \               kerberos
ELF 7bfcc000-7c000000   Deferred        wintrust<elf>
  \-PE  7bfd0000-7c000000   \               wintrust
ELF 7c000000-7c004000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7c00b000-7c019000   Deferred        libavahi-common.so.3
ELF 7c019000-7c031000   Deferred        userenv<elf>
  \-PE  7c020000-7c031000   \               userenv
ELF 7c031000-7c09e000   Deferred        setupapi<elf>
  \-PE  7c040000-7c09e000   \               setupapi
ELF 7c09e000-7c0d3000   Deferred        secur32<elf>
  \-PE  7c0a0000-7c0d3000   \               secur32
ELF 7c0d3000-7c0e8000   Deferred        rasdlg<elf>
  \-PE  7c0e0000-7c0e8000   \               rasdlg
ELF 7c0e8000-7c104000   Deferred        rasapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7c0f0000-7c104000   \               rasapi32
ELF 7c104000-7c135000   Deferred        netapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7c110000-7c135000   \               netapi32
ELF 7c135000-7c175000   Deferred        winspool<elf>
  \-PE  7c140000-7c175000   \               winspool
ELF 7c175000-7c267000   Deferred        comdlg32<elf>
  \-PE  7c180000-7c267000   \               comdlg32
ELF 7c267000-7c291000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  7c270000-7c291000   \               iphlpapi
ELF 7c291000-7c34a000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  7c2a0000-7c34a000   \               winmm
ELF 7c34a000-7c400000   Deferred        msvcrt<elf>
  \-PE  7c360000-7c400000   \               msvcrt
ELF 7c407000-7c432000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  7c410000-7c432000   \               msacm32
ELF 7c432000-7c4bd000   Deferred        libgmp.so.10
ELF 7c4bd000-7c4f3000   Deferred        libhogweed.so.4
ELF 7c4f3000-7c52f000   Deferred        libnettle.so.6
ELF 7c52f000-7c6b0000   Deferred        libunistring.so.2
ELF 7c6b0000-7c6ce000   Deferred        libidn2.so.0
ELF 7c6ce000-7c81c000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF 7c81c000-7c9b2000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.30
ELF 7c9b2000-7c9d2000   Deferred        bcrypt<elf>
  \-PE  7c9c0000-7c9d2000   \               bcrypt
ELF 7c9d2000-7caa2000   Deferred        crypt32<elf>
  \-PE  7c9e0000-7caa2000   \               crypt32
ELF 7caa2000-7cc84000   Deferred        mshtml<elf>
  \-PE  7cac0000-7cc84000   \               mshtml
ELF 7cc84000-7cd00000   Deferred        wininet<elf>
  \-PE  7cc90000-7cd00000   \               wininet
ELF 7ce03000-7ce17000   Deferred        psapi<elf>
  \-PE  7ce10000-7ce17000   \               psapi
ELF 7ce17000-7ce39000   Deferred        explorerframe<elf>
  \-PE  7ce20000-7ce39000   \               explorerframe
ELF 7ce39000-7ce61000   Deferred        mpr<elf>
  \-PE  7ce40000-7ce61000   \               mpr
ELF 7ce61000-7cf00000   Deferred        urlmon<elf>
  \-PE  7ce70000-7cf00000   \               urlmon
ELF 7d001000-7d006000   Deferred        libkeyutils.so.1
ELF 7d006000-7d01b000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.6
ELF 7d01b000-7d0ac000   Deferred        ieframe<elf>
  \-PE  7d020000-7d0ac000   \               ieframe
ELF 7d0ac000-7d0c4000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 7d0c4000-7d0de000   Deferred        wsock32<elf>
  \-PE  7d0d0000-7d0de000   \               wsock32
ELF 7d224000-7d25c000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7d230000-7d25c000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7d25c000-7d263000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7d263000-7d26f000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7d26f000-7d282000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7d282000-7d286000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7d286000-7d293000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7d293000-7d29f000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7d29f000-7d2a6000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7d2a6000-7d2aa000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7d2aa000-7d2b4000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF 7d2b4000-7d2cf000   Deferred        libbsd.so.0
ELF 7d2cf000-7d2d6000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7d2d6000-7d2da000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7d2da000-7d306000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7d306000-7d450000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7d450000-7d465000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7d468000-7d46d000   Deferred        libcom_err.so.2
ELF 7d46d000-7d476000   Deferred        libffi.so.6
ELF 7d476000-7d47d000   Deferred        libnss_dns.so.2
ELF 7d47f000-7d50f000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7d490000-7d50f000   \               winex11
ELF 7d50f000-7d523000   Deferred        msimg32<elf>
  \-PE  7d510000-7d523000   \               msimg32
ELF 7d523000-7d569000   Deferred        usp10<elf>
  \-PE  7d530000-7d569000   \               usp10
ELF 7d569000-7d6a3000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7d570000-7d6a3000   \               comctl32
ELF 7d6a3000-7d6c7000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7d6b0000-7d6c7000   \               imm32
ELF 7d80a000-7d83c000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7d83c000-7d887000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7d887000-7d8a6000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7d8a6000-7d8e0000   Deferred        libpng16.so.16
ELF 7d8e0000-7d99d000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7d9b7000-7d9f2000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7d9c0000-7d9f2000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7da20000-7daa1000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7da30000-7daa1000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7daa1000-7dbfb000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7dac0000-7dbfb000   \               ole32
ELF 7dbfb000-7dd2d000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7dc10000-7dd2d000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7dd2d000-7dd4b000   Deferred        jsproxy<elf>
  \-PE  7dd30000-7dd4b000   \               jsproxy
ELF 7dd4b000-7dd88000   Dwarf           winhttp<elf>
  \-PE  7dd50000-7dd88000   \               winhttp
ELF 7dd88000-7de01000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7dda0000-7de01000   \               advapi32
ELF 7de01000-7df2f000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7de10000-7df2f000   \               gdi32
ELF 7df2f000-7e137000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7df40000-7e137000   \               user32
ELF 7e137000-7e1ad000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e140000-7e1ad000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7e1ad000-7eb6c000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7e1c0000-7eb6c000   \               shell32
ELF 7eb6c000-7eb80000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7eb80000-7eb9b000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7eb9b000-7eba9000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7eba9000-7ebb3000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF 7eee4000-7efe6000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efe6000-7f000000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000   \               version
ELF f7b26000-f7b2b000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f7b2b000-f7d07000   Dwarf           libc.so.6
ELF f7d07000-f7d26000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF f7d40000-f7ef7000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f7ef9000-f7f21000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f7f24000-f7f26000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    00000032    0
    00000024    0
    00000021    0
    0000001c    0
    00000018    0
    00000013    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000011 winedevice.exe
    00000019    0
    00000017    0
    00000016    0
    00000012    0
0000001a plugplay.exe
    0000001e    0
    0000001d    0
    0000001b    0
0000001f winedevice.exe
    00000027    0
    00000023    0
    00000022    0
    00000020    0
00000025 explorer.exe
    0000002a    0
    00000029    0
    00000028    0
    00000026    0
00000030 rpcss.exe
    00000051    0
    00000036    0
    00000035    0
    00000034    0
    00000033    0
    00000031    0
00000047 (D) C:\Program Files (x86)\Electronic Arts\Ultima Online Classic\UO.bin
    00000097    0
    00000081    0
    00000080    0
    0000007f    0 <==
    0000007e    0
    0000007d    0
    0000007c    0
    0000007b    0
    00000078    0
    00000074    0
    00000073    0
    0000006e    0
    0000006d    0
    0000006c    0
    0000006b    0
    0000006a    0
    00000069    0
    00000068    0
    00000067    0
    00000066   -1
    00000065    0
    00000064    0
    00000063    0
    00000062    0
    00000061   -1
    00000060   -1
    0000005f    0
    0000005e    0
    0000005d    0
    0000005c    0
    0000005b    0
    0000005a    0
    00000059    0
    00000058    0
    00000057    0
    00000056    0
    00000055    0
    00000054    0
    00000053    0
    00000050    0
    0000004e    0
    0000004d    0
    0000004c    0
    00000048    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-3.16
    Platform: i386 (WOW64)
    Version: Windows 7
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 4.15.0-34-generic
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.